# Setting html classes CSS with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have an element

```
<div class="accordion">hello</div>
```

and when an event happens(button clicked) several classes are added and removed to the element found above.

The first phase adds the class `beginning-transition`

```
<div class="accordion beginning-transition">hello</div>
```

The second phase adds the class `middle-transition` and removes the `beginning-transition` class.

```
<div class="accordion middle-transition">hello</div>
```

The final stage removes the `middle-transition` class

```
<div class="accordion">hello</div>
```

During this button click event I run a formula that determines the height of the div.

```
var element = $('.accordion');
element.css('height', 10);
$(element + '.beginning-transition').css('height', 100);
$(element + '.middle-transition').css('height', 200);
```

The problem is that when the two classes `beginning-transition` and `middle-transition` are added to the class, the CSS height does not change from 10px.

The following line below:

```
element.css('height', 10);
```

Seems to override these two css rules:

```
$(element + '.beginning-transition').css('height', 100);
$(element + '.middle-transition').css('height', 200);
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can we have a jsfiddle?

Comment: Ergh. That will take me awhile to do and I'll have a hard time replicating it to a jsfiddle. I can tell you though that the css set with a jquery is the issue.

Comment: Self contained, minimal, reproducible example is pretty much required (not really, but it will prevent downvotes and closevotes and get more answers).

Comment: I understand. I expected this to happen. I just don't have the time to sit down and replicate it :(

Comment: Ok, fine, I think I know what you're talking about. Posting answer…

Comment: Try specifying the `px`:  `.css('height', '200px');`

Comment: Pretty sure you can't concatenate a selector like that when `element` is a jQuery object.

Comment: This is not valid syntax: `$(element + '.beginning-transition').css('height', 100);`. You are adding a string to a jQuery object and trying to generate a new selection, you are not setting a CSS class.

Comment: @christian314159 I stupidly forgot to check console, and it looks like you are correct with that statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var element = $('.accordion');
element.css('height', 10);
$(element + '.beginning-transition').css('height', 100);
$(element + '.middle-transition').css('height', 200);
```

So you're assigning a height… then assigning an override? Just do it once.

```
var element = $('.accordion')[0];
if (element.classList.contains('beginning-transition')) {
    element.style.height = '100px';
} else if (element.classList.contains('middle-transition')) {
    element.style.height = '200px';
} else {
    element.style.height = '10px';
}
```

That's vanilla JS, but it's the same thing (with different names) in jQuery.

The actual problem is that you were adding a jQuery element list (`$('.accordion')`) to a string (the class). That doesn't make sense. To fix the problem changing your code as little as possible, make it:

```
var element = $('.accordion');
element.css('height', 10);
$('.accordion.beginning-transition').css('height', 100);
$('.accordion.middle-transition').css('height', 200);
```

When in doubt, debug with your console.

Comment: Hmm. After fixing the selector the initial height setter `element.css('height', 10);` still overrides the other CSS rules defined. I'm going to have to debug this some more.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to concatenate a selector string to `element` which is a jQuery object. That's not going to work, since jQuery objects aren't converted to their selector strings when converted into strings, so you'll just get a nonsensical selector string as a result.

If you need to save the original selector string for later use you need to save it separately:

```
var selector = '.accordion';

// Or var element = $(selector); element.css(...); if you need the element var too
$(selector).css('height', 10);
$(selector + '.beginning-transition').css('height', 100);
$(selector + '.middle-transition').css('height', 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

JQUERY
    $(".accordion").click(function(){

```
setTimeout(function () {$(".accordion").addClass("BT")}, 1000);
setTimeout(function () {$(".accordion").addClass("MT")}, 2000);
setTimeout(function () {$(".accordion").removeClass("BT")}, 3000);
setTimeout(function () {$(".accordion").removeClass("MT")}, 3000);



 });
```

CSS

```
.accordion {
width: 399px;
height:100px;
background: black;  
}

.BT {

height:200px;
}

.MT {
height: 300px;
}
```